# Can I reset a jQuery sticky navbar function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new here and I'm facing a little problem with a jQuery script I'm using to change my CSS when my sticky navbar scrolls over a certain section.

First, I'm using one class called ".stickychange", which is the trigger for the jQuery function. On this section, I'm using a background-image (one picture I've taken personally), and I want my white navbar to become transparent black when it's over this said section. And it's working like a charm. But after this section, I have a white section and I want my navbar to take its default style, but it doesn't.
If I'm scrolling back to the top, it's taking its default settings, but if I'm scrolling past the .stickychange, it would stay with the tweaked CSS styles.

Do you know how to reset a function, or at least, stop it when it reaches a certain point?

Here's the code, it's a basic code if you wanna change styles on elements while scrolling :

```
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var startchange = $(".stickychange");
 var offset = startchange.offset();

 if (startchange) {
     $(document).scroll(function () {
         scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
         if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
             $("#menu_top").css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
             $("#menu_top").css('transition', 'all 0.2s ease-in');
             $("#menu_top a").addClass("stickyspecial");
            $("#menu_top h2").addClass("stickyname");
         } else {
             $('#menu_top').css('background-color', '#fff');
             $('#menu_top a').removeClass("stickyspecial");
             $('#menu_top h2').removeClass("stickyname");
         }
     });
 }
```

Thanks, guys in advance! :)

Comment: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});` try it out :)

Comment: Try to get height of the `div` and add this to your `if` like: `scroll_start > offset.top && scroll_start < offset.top + startchange.outerHeight()`

Comment: You probably need to modify your if statement. At the moment you're testing if you're scrolled down to the element, but you have no test to see if you're scrolled _past_ the element. Something like `if (scroll_start > offset.top && scroll_start < offset.top + offset.height()) {`.

Comment: thanks guys, the startchange.outerHeight() did the trick! :)
I'll try the other codes if I can make it useful to me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `height` of the `div` and add this to your `if`.

```
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var startchange = $(".stickychange");
 var offset = startchange.offset();

 // Get the height with padding and border
 // You could use .height() if you just want the height of the div.
 var endchange = startchange.outerHeight(); 

 if (startchange) {
     $(document).scroll(function () {
         scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
         if (scroll_start > offset.top && scroll_start < offset.top + endchange) { //<- Add it here  
             $("#menu_top").css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
             $("#menu_top").css('transition', 'all 0.2s ease-in');
             $("#menu_top a").addClass("stickyspecial");
            $("#menu_top h2").addClass("stickyname");
         } else {
             $('#menu_top').css('background-color', '#fff');
             $('#menu_top a').removeClass("stickyspecial");
             $('#menu_top h2').removeClass("stickyname");
         }
     });
 }
```

If you're using `margin` on the `div` and want it to be applied, use [.outerHeight(true)](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/).

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the trick, it works like a charm!
I'm actually new to jS/jQuery but i'm trying to do my best to understand correctly how it works.
So, startchange.outerHeight() did the trick and i'm able to change the style past the first .stickychange class.
Do you know how I can trigger this a second time if, for example, my third section has a .stickychange class too ?

Comment: I think this would be worth a new question on SO. Poorly I can't answer this at this moment.